# Showing exception error while trying to send emails with a sheet as an excel attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to send emails with a specific tab of a Google Spreadsheet as an Excel attachment to 40-50 students using  **installable** edit trigger. It is showing

> Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permissions: googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request.

I reviewed several related posts and answer at Stackoverflow and Google but can't find anyway to do it manually.

My codes are:

```
function classAttendance(e){ 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var sheetName = dashboard.getRange("A4").getValue(); 
  var sheetw = dashboard.getRange("A8");
  var sheetw2 = dashboard.getRange("G8");
  
  if (sheetName == 'All'){
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6' && e.range.getValue() === "Send Emails") {
      sheetw.setValue('Sending emails to all students. Please Wait!').setFontColor('Red');
      //refreshSheet();
      sendEmails();
      sheetw.setValue('You may take class attendance now. Thank You!').setFontColor('Green');
      sheetw2.setValue('You may do manual entry now. Thank You!').setFontColor('Green');
    }    
    if ((e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6') && (e.range.getValue() === "Start 1-Period" || e.range.getValue() === "Start 2-Period" || e.range.getValue() === "Error Correction")) {
      dashboard.getRange("C6").setValue('Please Select');
    }    
  }  
}
    function sendEmails(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var ssID = ss.getId();
      var sheetName = ss.getName(); 
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sheet1 = sh.getSheetByName("TempDataSet");
      var shID = sheet1.getSheetId().toString();
     
      var subject = 'Your Attendance Record at BDU';
      var body = 'Dear Student,'+ '\n\n' + 'Greetings! Please find the attendance record attached for your reference.' + '\n\n' + 'Thank you.';
      
      var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
      var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;
    
      var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
      var contents = result.getContent();
      var column = 3;
      contents.sort({column: column, ascending:true});
             
      var sheet2 = sh.getSheetByName('StudentList');  
      var data = sheet2.getLastRow();
      var students = [];
      var students = sheet2.getRange(2, 6, data).getValues();  
      
      for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){ // you are looping through rows and selecting the 1st and only column index
        if (students[i][0] !== ''){           
          MailApp.sendEmail(students[i][0].toString(), subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xls", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xls"}]});     
        } 
      } 
    }
```

[image: library and the codes]

I created a standalone scripts where there are many functions including `sendEmails()` at my Google drive, then invoked the scripts as a library to my Google spreadsheet. Then I called the library in the script editor of my Google Sheet and also created an onEdit trigger for sendEmails(). All other functions in the library called are working fine.

Comment: What type of trigger? Installed or simple?

Comment: Have you looked into view> executions for error logs?

Comment: simple onEdit trigger with standalone scripts

Comment: Simple trigger  function name should be ``onEdit``. Yours is `sendEmails`. Simple triggers will only work with "bound" scripts not "standalone". Consider reviewing the core documentation. Also Simple triggers can't send email. You would need installable triggers.

Comment: Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request

Comment: Sorry, My trigger is installed and script is standalone. I think it is the permission issues as showing in the executions. How to overcome it?

Comment: If your script is "standalone", `SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` will return `null`. Review core documentation or explain 1. How you go to the script from Google sheets. 2. How did you set up the trigger . Add these details + 3. The error message to your question by [edit]ing it

Comment: I created a standalone scripts where there are many functions including sendEmails() at my Google drive, then invoked the scripts as a library to my Google spreadsheet. then I called the library in the script editor of my Google Sheet and also created an onEdit trigger for sendEmails(). All other functions in the library called are working fine. here is the case of permission as outlined in the post. thanks

Comment: *also created an onEdit trigger for sendEmails()* Explain how you created the trigger?. Could you show the full function in script editor including library name and how you invoke the library scripts.

Comment: Please check the revised code at the post. Then I wrote in my Google Sheet's Script Editor, function classAttendance2(e){
  mse.classAttendance(e);
} where mse is the identifier of the library I created.

Comment: Please check the attached image as well for details. And the revised codes are at the post. And the onEdit trigger is created for classAttendance2() at my Google sheet current project's triggers

Comment: Remove the edit trigger and readd it. That should trigger authorization again. Try run `classAttendance2` manually from script editor> that should also trigger authorization.

Comment: @TheMaster Excellent. It works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library seems to be added after adding the trigger. Hence authorization scopes are missing from previous authorization. The following should trigger re-authorization:

- Remove the installed edit trigger and re-add it.
- Click `Run` button after selecting `classAttendance2` manually from script editor>